# Application crashes when clearing the QTreeWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget

My application is crashing with a BAD_ACCESS when quitting and when clearing the QTreeWidget.

This is how I'm populating the first level of the tree:

```
std::set<UrlItem>::iterator i;

for(i = crawler->getUrls()->begin() ; i != crawler->getUrls()->end() ; i++) {
    QList<QString> cells;
    cells.append(i->url);
    cells.append(i->httpStatusMessage);
    cells.append(QString("%1").arg(i->statusCode));

    QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->resultTreeView, QStringList(cells));

    ui->resultTreeView->addTopLevelItem(item);
}
```

I believe that the header item is causing the crash:

```
ui->resultTreeView->setHeaderItem(new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->resultTreeView, QStringList(headers)));
```

What am I doing to cause this crash? The item that is dynamically allocated has the tree widget as it's parent so it should only be destroyed when the tree widget is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was setting the header the wrong way.

This works fine:

```
QList<QString> headers;
headers.append(tr("Url"));
headers.append(tr("Message"));
headers.append(tr("Status code"));

ui->resultTreeView->setHeaderLabels(QStringList(headers));
```

Now, what *setHeaderItem* was supposed to do and why it crashed my application I don't know but the code above achieved the desired effect.

Comment: You can use `QStringList headers; headers << tr("Url") << ...` to insert into the headers, this way you don't need to create a temporary QStringList. (And QStringList is effectively only a wrapper for QList<QString> anyway with some nicer overloads.)